# Как вставить несколько полей из определенной таблицы во временную таблицу?

Tags: mysql

У меня есть временная таблица:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE TT_name (ObjectName varchar(45) NOT NULL, 
                                MessageNo int NOT NULL,  
                                _Order TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,  
                                PRIMARY KEY (ObjectName)) ENGINE = MyISAM;
```

Нужно:

1. выбрать из таблицы 'Table_name' запись с самой давней датой в поле
   '_Order' и 'MessageNo' = 1;
2. вставить данные из выбранной ранее записи во временную таблицу ( поля '_Order' и 'MessageNo')  и в поле 'ObjectName' вставить определенное значение (например 'EntityModelName');

Как это можно сделать?

Comment: `insert into TT_name(...) select ... from Table_name where MessageNo=1 order by _Order desc limit 1`

Comment: а как в этот insert в поле 'ObjectName' вставить определенное значение (например 'EntityModelName');

Comment: select может выбирать не только значения из колонок, вы вполне можете написать `select ..., 'EntityModelName', ... from ...`

Comment: да, решение подходит. Спасибо :)

Comment: Наверное вам нужно перенести коммент как ответ на вопрос, чтобы я мог отметить как решение.

Comment: order by _Order - он часом не финальную временную TT_name таблицу сортирует? Или все же достает поле с самой давней записью из табл. Table_name и вставляет ее во временную?

Comment: нет. order by относится к фразе select и работает с ее таблицей, т.е. Table_name

Comment: По возможности, подскажите пожалуйста на еще один вопрос https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/955904/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-union-all-%D0%B8-order-by

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
insert into TT_name(ObjectName, MessageNo, _Order)
select 'EntityModelName', MessageNo, _Order
  from Table_name
 where MessageNo=1
 order by _Order desc limit 1
```