# Как правильно использовать UNION ALL и order by?

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть несколько запросов, которые пытаюсь объединить:

```
          SELECT 'object1', MessageNo, _Order FROM _Object1Changes WHERE MessageNo=0 AND Node='33' order by _Order desc  LIMIT 1
UNION ALL SELECT 'object2', MessageNo, _Order FROM _Object2Changes WHERE MessageNo=0 AND Node='33' order by _Order desc  LIMIT 1
UNION ALL SELECT 'object3', MessageNo, _Order FROM _Object3Changes WHERE MessageNo=0 AND Node='33' order by _Order desc  LIMIT 1
UNION ALL SELECT 'object4', MessageNo, _Order FROM _Object4Changes WHERE MessageNo=0 AND Node='33' order by _Order desc  LIMIT 1;
```

Error Code: 1221. Incorrect usage of UNION and ORDER BY

Или пробую так:

```
          SELECT 'object1', MessageNo, MIN(_Order) FROM _Object1Changes WHERE MessageNo=0 AND Node='33' LIMIT 1
UNION ALL SELECT 'object2', MessageNo, MIN(_Order) FROM _Object2Changes WHERE MessageNo=0 AND Node='33'  LIMIT 1
UNION ALL SELECT 'object3', MessageNo, MIN(_Order) FROM _Object3Changes WHERE MessageNo=0 AND Node='33'LIMIT 1
UNION ALL SELECT 'object4', MessageNo, MIN(_Order) FROM _Object4Changes WHERE MessageNo=0 AND Node='33' LIMIT 1;
```

Получаю таблицу с одной записью, 'object1', null, null.
Цель получить результат из нескольких таблиц, где из каждой таблицы берет запись с минимальным значением _Order и Node='33'

Как это можно исправить?

Comment: примените скобки `(select ...order by limit) union all (select ...)`

Comment: To apply ORDER BY or LIMIT to an individual SELECT, place the clause inside the parentheses that enclose the SELECT. [UNION Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/union.html).

Comment: Да, это то что нужно. В чем отличие MIN(_Order) и order by _Order в данном случае?

Comment: *В чем отличие MIN(_Order) и order by _Order в данном случае?* Одно тёплое, другое мягкое. Там, где MIN() - можете убрать LIMIT, он не имеет смысла. И вариант с MIN() гарантированно не медленнее, чем вариант с ORDER BY (если оптимизатор не ошибётся, что редкость).

Comment: но с MIN получаю таблицу с пустыми записями например 'object1', null, null от таблиц, где нет необходимых данных и сколько он записей выдаст если несколько записей с минимальным значением _Order?

Comment: Выносите на отдельный ответ, отмечу как решение.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В главе документации [UNION Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/union.html):

> To apply ORDER BY or LIMIT to an individual SELECT, place the clause inside the parentheses that enclose the SELECT

Заключите отдельные подзапросы в скобки:

```
(SELECT a FROM t1 WHERE a=10 AND B=1 ORDER BY a LIMIT 10)
UNION
(SELECT a FROM t2 WHERE a=11 AND B=2 ORDER BY a LIMIT 10);
```